# Testing compatibility of shaders

Tags: opengl, testing, glsl, integration-testing

When I develop shader code on my machine I often find myself in the situation where the shader works perfectly on my machine, but on other graphic cards, drivers, operating systems, etc. it doesn't.

How to achieve compatibility of shaders?

I see a few approches:

- Test on many different systems. But which systems to choose? Testing with every card on every OS and every driver is not realistic. Maybe we can assume that the vendors care for backward compatibility? In this case testing with old cards and drivers might be sufficient.
- Ask the driver for a specific version and core profile. This helps a bit, but the drivers seem very lenient, allowing me to code things that aren't in the spec.
- Code checkers that check the code for strict compatibility with a certain spec. There don't seen to be such tools around.
- Don't bother and wait for bug-reports from users.Yet the error messages generated by the drivers are rather poor, and the observed behaviour might be as un-insightful as a black screen.

I'm targeting Win/Linux/OSX platforms. Not consoles.

Comment: Do you have specific errors that are cropping up? We can't really help with generic advice.

Comment: This is not about a specific error (missing "in" on function parameters would be one). I'm more interested how compatibility issues are handled in, say, commertial applications. Many problems arise outside the shader too. Maybe shaders always tested in situ. That would widen the scope of the question further.

Comment: The answer also depends a lot on which hardware you are targeting. For consoles, testing is ways easier since there is just a very limited number of configurations available. For PC/Mac, I would test agains the most current drivers of the three big hardware vendors (NVIDIA, AMD, Intel).

Comment: @BDL good point. Edited the question. Why the most current drivers? Many users won't have them installed.

Comment: Because if it's not working with an old driver version, you can tell the users to update. The other way round is much harder to argue.

Comment: "Test on many different systems. But which systems to choose?" - If you have statistics, you can filter by those that are used by your users the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Khronos has released [OpenGL / OpenGL ES Reference Compiler](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/Reference-Compiler/) that can be used to validate shader's source code. From the site:

> The primary purpose of the reference compiler is to identify shader
>   portability issues.